# How to consume WCF service from BizTalk 2010

Tags: wcf, xsd, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have a web service that I need to consume from BizTalk orchestration.
I've defined message schemas which I use in BizTalk, they look like

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
    <xs:schema 
        xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" 
        xmlns="http://www.myapp.com/schemas/IntegrationApplication-instance" 
        xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" 
        xmlns:ns0="https://DTIB.PropertySchema" 
        elementFormDefault="qualified" 
        targetNamespace="http://www.myapp.com/schemas/IntegrationApplication-instance" 
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xs:include schemaLocation=".\CommonTypes.xsd" />
      <xs:element name="ProviderRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Header" type="HeaderType" />
            <xs:element name="Parameters" type="ParametersType" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
```

In WCF service I have methods defined like

```
public ProviderResponse Provide(ProviderRequest providerRequest) {...}
```

where `ProviderRequest` is defined like

```
        [DataContract(Namespace = "http://www.myapp.com/schemas/IntegrationApplication-instance")]
        public class ProviderRequest
        {
            [DataMember]
            public Header Header { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public Parameter[] Parameters { get; set; }
        }
```

When I create send port and try to send a ProviderRequest message it fails with different errors.

What's the best method to consume a WCF service which uses the same schemas as defined in BizTalk project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to run an instance of your service and then "Add Generated Items" -> "Consume WCF Service" from within Visual Studio.

This will generate your service message XSDs and port types and is a low-friction way of doing what you are trying to do.

Comment: I did try this way, it gives me an error "There was a failure executing the receive pipeline: "Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines.XMLReceive, Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Source: "XML disassembler" Receive Port: "WcfReceivePort_BizTalkWcfService/Provider" URI: "/BizTalkWcfService/Provider.svc" Reason: Cannot locate document specification because multiple schemas matched the message type". It only got working when I switch on Allow Unrecognized Message option in XMLReceive pipeline properties

Comment: @Javos - This is a versionning issue. You have two assemblies with the same message defined in them, so when BizTalk tries to deserialize your xml into a message it does not know which one to use. This is bad practise and can cause runtime failures so you should remove the message definition from one or the other assembly. Please note that these assemblies are not necessarily part of the same BizTalk application.

Comment: OK but if I want to use shared message schema between my systems what should I do then?

Comment: You can still share the message schema between your biztalk applications. You only need to ensure the message is defined in one schema only. You can then create project references in visual studio to the assembly which contains the schema you want to use in your other biztalk applications.

Comment: Consider the following: I have BizTalk project and inside it I have placed xsd schemas for messages. Those schemas are in namespace "A". I have another web service, it uses datacontract with namespaces "A" too. So when I add a service reference to the first project which is Biztalk, VS generates schemas for datacontracts that are in the second project. Thus I have 2 schemas with the same namespace and root element.

Comment: @Javros - Please post a new question in BizTalk with you final comment as the question. I will answer it there. This comments thread is getting too long. If you feel that I have helped you with your original question feel free to upvote my answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3291/discussion-between-javros-and-hugh-jadick)

Answer (score 0):

Quite interesting question, a scenario that might happen to others.

Here are some suggestions.

**Most common case:** You need to consume a service and want to use those messages
- Use hugh's suggestion "Add generated item..."

**Less common case:** You have already created a schema that a service also uses (the same)
- Use hugh's suggestion "Add generated item..."
- Remove the schema that is a duplicate, either your own or from the created

**Not so common case:** You want to consume two services that uses the same schema
- Use hugh's suggestion "Add generated item..."
- Remove the schema that is a duplicate from one of the generated

**Have never happened to me case:** You have already created a schema that a service also uses (NOT the same, but same root name and name space)
- There is nothing to do, this will not work (out of the box)